# Why sscanf() or strtoll() does not convert a hex string more than 9 bytes to hex number

Tags: c, string

eg. I have a hex string "1800272100A1". I tried converting it to hex no. 1800272100A1 using ssanf() as follows,

```
   sscanf(out1,"%lld",&r1);
```

where out1 contains above string and r1 is long long int.

And even strtoll() fails to convert the same string,

```
  r1 = strtoll(out1,NULL,16);
```

Comment: Your description of the problem consists of only the word "fails". What *precisely* goes wrong?

Comment: I mean it does not convert the complete string to Hex number.

Comment: In above example the i/p is "1800272100A1" and sscanf() propduces 1800272100 as output which is incomplete and expected output is 1800272100A1.

Comment: You are asking `sscanf` to read in a long long decimal value. It will stop at the first non-digit.

Comment: You're saying you tried "converting it to hex no." -- Please state what the difference is between a "decimal number" (number, not string!) and a "hex number"...

Comment: `long long r1 = strtoll("123456789abcdef", NULL, 16);` converts perfectly fine to `r1` being `81 985 529 216 486 895`.

Comment: Oh..thanks David...... so which format specifier will be suitable for this conversion?

Comment: What about reading the documentation?

Comment: Or the answer below? ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using `%lld` format specifier. For `%lld`, only `0-9` are valid digits. Use `%llx` to convert it properly. `%llx` is the format specifier for **hexadecimal** representation of `long long int` integers.

In your input, `1800272100A1`, `'A'` is the first invalid digit for `%lld`. So it converts till before `'A'`.

I am not sure why `strtoll` is failing. I read its documentation, your syntax seems fine.

Comment: @Abhay : I hope my answer solved your problem. If it didn't please comment, if it did then please accept it. Accepting it will save other users' time as accepted answer will not attract other users unnecessarily, as you have been already provided with correct solution. Thanks.